# android recyclerview doesn't display items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to show these items inside my recyclerview but it doesn't show at all and I can't see the error. Maybe you guys can help me out.

MainActivity.java

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec);
List<MenuData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        MenuRecAdapter menuRecAdapter = new MenuRecAdapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(menuRecAdapter);
```

RecyclerView adapter:

```
    public class MenuRecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecViewHolder>{

    private List<MenuData> mList;
    Activity context;

    public MenuRecAdapter(List<MenuData> mList){
        this.mList = mList;
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
        return mList.size();
    }

    public RecViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menuitem, viewGroup, false);
        RecViewHolder pvh = new RecViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecViewHolder holder, int i){
        holder.menuTeXT.setText(mList.get(i).text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

ViewHolder of the items:

```
  public class RecViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView menuTeXT;

    public RecViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        menuTeXT = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuTXT);
    }
}
```

and the data I want to put into my recyclerview (what doesn't show):

```
    class MenuData {

    String text;

    MenuData(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    private List<MenuData> list;

    private void initializeData(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new MenuData("Featured"));
        list.add(new MenuData("Categories"));
        list.add(new MenuData("Sell"));
        list.add(new MenuData("Settings"));
        list.add(new MenuData("Logout"));
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you create an object of MenuData and call initializeData() to make a list and then pass it to adapter?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: when you write `MenuRecAdapter menuRecAdapter = new MenuRecAdapter(list);`  is the `list` already created ?

Comment: Like `List<MenuData> list = new ArrayList<>();` ?

Comment: yeah but for now `list` is just empty. just after `List<MenuData> list = new ArrayList<>();` add some data. like `list.add("something");` and run

Comment: In MainActivity.Java?

Comment: You are doing it a little different than i thought. Sould i suggest a work around (little different from your code) as an ans?

Comment: Maybe this’ll help save someone some time/headache: make sure you’ve set your layout file!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In MainActivity

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("something1");
list.add("something2");

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

MenuRecAdapter menuRecAdapter = new MenuRecAdapter(list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(menuRecAdapter);
```

RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class MenuRecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<>();
Activity context;

public MenuRecAdapter(ArrayList<String> mList){
    this.mList = mList;
}

public int getItemCount(){
    return mList.size();
}

public RecViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menuitem, viewGroup, false);
    RecViewHolder pvh = new RecViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(RecViewHolder holder, int i){
    holder.menuTeXT.setText(mList.get(i));
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

and ViewHolder remains same...

```
public class RecViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView menuTeXT;

public RecViewHolder(View itemView){
    super(itemView);

    menuTeXT = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menuTXT);
}
}
```

also get rid of MenuData class. The above code should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, LinearLayoutManager is important here.

Comment: This is a poorly written answer that doesn't explain at all what the fix is, just a bunch of code. How did this answer get 53 upvotes? The problem was simply that the list was empty?

Answer (score 5):

As it was mentioned above in comments, the problem might be in non-specifying the `layoutManager` attribute of the `RecyclerView`.

The `layoutManager` can be specified either in XML-file or dynamically in Java code.

Example of Java code from the answer above:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

To add layoutManager via XML use the appropriate attribute:

```
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
         
   app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

This fixed problem for me.

Comment: Thank you, dude!  Literally, you've made my day.  Spent about 8 hours figuring out what's wrong with my custom RecyclerView adapter.  The issue was that I haven't specified layout manager to recycler view itself.  Official docs mentions about layout manager, but never shows how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not getting any data, I guess the problem happens at the time you pass the list into your adapter. I see you didn't make copy of your list, so you are passing the reference of the list directly into the adapter. I suggest you to try 
`MenuRecAdapter menuRecAdapter = new MenuRecAdapter(new Arraylist(list));`

Comment: Still getting no items

Comment: I didn't see you created any instance of MenuData in your code. Of course your list is empty.